# Java generics & incompatible types using <S extends {class}>

Tags: java, generics

```
abstract class AbsClass {}

class MyAbs extends AbsClass {}

class MyClass<S extends AbsClass> {
    S getObj() {
        return new MyAbs();
    }
}
```

Getting compiler issue:

> Error:(33, 16) java: incompatible types: MyAbs cannot be converted to S

What is the correct way to do this?

Edit:
I was hoping to be able to intialize MyClass{MyAbs} then call getObj() which would return me a MyAbs object. With Andy's answer, I would have to cast the AbsClass to MyAbs or MySecondAbs which was what I was trying to avoid

Comment: Remove the `<S extends AbsClass>`, and change `S getObj()` to either `MyAbs getObj()` or `AbsClass getObj()`. As it stands, there is no reason to have a type variable.

Comment: Can you describe what you want when saying "to do this" ?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to intialize MyClass<MyAbs> then call getObj() which would return me a MyAbs object. With Andy's answer, I would have to cast the AbsClass to MyAbs or MySecondAbs which was what I was trying to avoid

Answer (score 5):

Andy has described how to fix the problem, I'll try to explain why.

`S` is not guaranteed to be assignable to `MyAbs`, only to `AbsClass`, and each instance will specify a subclass of `AbsClass`.

Consider:

```
class MyOtherAbs extends AbsClass {}

MyClass myClass = new MyClass<MyOtherAbsClass>{};
```

This would conflict with what you have.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comments it looks like you want to achieve the above.  The challenge is what if `MyOtherAbs` has a constructor with arguments?  Or is implemented as a Singleton (i.e. a private constructor and static `getInstance()`).  In short, there is no guaranteed unified way you can construct these.  Further, due to type erasure, at runtime, the concept of S is gone, so you cannot do something like:

```
return new S();
```

You basically have two alternatives, one is to use subclassing:

```
public interface AbsClassFactory<S extends AbsClass>{ //takes the place of MyClass
    public S getInstance();
}

MyAbsFactory implements AbsClassFactory<MyAbs>{
    public MyAbs getInstance(){
        return new MyAbs(); //or however MyAbs is instantiated
    }
}
```

The other option is reflection:

```
class MyClass {
    public <S extends AbsClass> S getObj(Class<S> clazz) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Note that the second assumes there is a no arg constructor available and will throw a runtime exception if one is not.

Comment: Your example is what I am trying to accomplish, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: I'll expand answer to offer an alternative

Answer (score 3):

`S` extends `MyAbs`, not the other way around. any object of type `S` can be cast into `MyAbs`, but `MyAbs` cannot be cast into it's derived classes.

Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: All poodles are dogs, but not all dogs are poodles.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment it seems that you can accomplish the same using the `Supplier` interface:

```
Supplier<MyAbs> supp = MyAbs::new; // Constructor reference
MyAbs obj = supp.get();

Supplier<MySecondAbs> supp2 = MySecondAbs::new;
MySecondAbs obj2 = supp2.get();
```